# How to change the gtkmm code to gtk, c/c++?

Tags: gtk3, gtkmm

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/828251/how-to-design-login-page-with-gtk3-c-code), I want to design login page with gtk3 c++ code.

But, I find a gtkmm code for it in [here](http://www.mpshouse.com/?p=901):

I am new in GTK and I never work with gtkmm.

How to change the gtkmm code to gtk, c/c++?

Comment: If you are new to both GTK+ and gtkmm, I suggest that you read a GTK+ tutorial and ignore gtkmm. But if you really want to use C++, and understand C++, I suggest you read a gtkmm tutorial and use gtkmm.

Comment: @ murrayc: Thank you so much for your guide. But, I can't change the gtkmm code to gtk. If it possible help me to change it.

Comment: Gtkmm  *is* C++. There's some history here. The 'mm' in gtkmm is for '--' (minus-minus). It really means that gtkmm is the c++ library for gtk. (Gtk is more correctly called gtk+, because though it's pure C, the library implements a class/object system similar to C++)